$(1 + a)^\epsilon \le 1 + a \epsilon, 0 < \epsilon < 1, a>0$
$(1 + a)^\epsilon \le 1 + a \epsilon, 0 < \epsilon < 1, a>0$
While working out a proof for Jensen's inequality, I stumbled across this requirement.
The easier case was when $\epsilon = 1/m, (\exists m \in N), m > 1$
However for $\epsilon \in Q$ or $\epsilon \in P$, not able to come up a proof.
If anyone can try and provide a proof, it would be great.
I request avoid using Taylor Series or Jensen's inequality. Just from first principles, is it possible to prove?

If you have the case where $\epsilon = 1/q$, then the case where $\epsilon = p/q$ follows by the binomial theorem and the case of arbitrary real $\epsilon$ amounts to an argument by continuity/limits.

What does "$\epsilon \in Q$ or $\epsilon \in P$" mean?

Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question + please avoid "no clue" questions: what did you try? This elementary proof is very natural.

@AnneBauval Q means rational numbers and P means irrational numbers. I have mentioned it to highlight complications involved. I believe it is not "no clue" question as I mentioned how I came across this "requirement" of this theorem in another theorem I am working on.

@AnneBauval I have referred to the wiki article thank you, HOWEVER it depends on Jensen's inequality again for weighted AM and GM. I already mentioned that this I came across this theorem while working on a proof for Jensen's inequality.

Please have a more careful look at the link to Wikipedia which I provided you: the sketch of proof it gives did absolutely not  'depend on Jensen's inequality again for weighted AM and GM'. It was completely elementary. Whzt I mean by "no clue" is that you did not report any attempt to a proof this inequality, whereas you had it at your disposal.

I'm not sure if the first derivative test counts as "first principles" but here is one way to proceed. Fix $0 < \epsilon < 1$.
Define $\Phi(a) = 1+a\epsilon - (1+a)^\epsilon$ for  $a \ge 0$. Then $\Phi(0) = 0$ and $$\Phi'(a) = \epsilon - \epsilon(1+a)^{\epsilon - 1} = \epsilon(1 - (1+a)^{\epsilon - 1}) > 0$$
for all $a > 0$ because $\epsilon - 1 < 0$ and $1+a > 1$ imply $(1+a)^{\epsilon - 1} < 1$. According to the first derivative test $\Phi$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$ so that $\Phi(a) \ge \Phi(0)$ for all $a \ge 0$. This is the inequality you're looking for.

This proof is standard and this inequality even holds for every $a\ge-1$, since $\Phi$ is decreasing on $[-1,0]$. I am surprised not to find an older post about it.

@Umberto P. Thank you for providing a clear proof based on derivatives. It looks like there is no other way than to use calculus. I have attempted for $\epsilon=1/m, m \in N, m>1$, for $(1+a)^\frac{1}{m} = (1 + b) \rightarrow (1+a) \ge 1 + m b \rightarrow b \le a/m$. Therefore $(1+a)^\frac{1}{m} \le 1 + a/m$. But generalizing to $\epsilon$ I had problem.
